# Mono using MPAPI

Tags: c#, linux, mono, mpi

How do I include the mono MPAPI libraries in a program? is there a GMCS command or am I referring to the library wrong or is it for some reason not on my server?
To help, below is my mono version and the error message I get when trying to compile the code. Not seeing any good examples or documentation on this, and the program is compiling just fine in MS .NET But not mono on a remote server. =(

Here's my mono --version:

Mono JIT compiler version 2.0.1 (tarball)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none

And the error message upon trying to compile:
(relates to line: "using MPAPI;")

```
    Program.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MPAPI' could not be found.
    Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly do you compile it? This is usual error saying what it really is: assembly reference is missing (you can reference an assembly with -r switch, but the build system is really recommended here):

```
 (g)mcs -r:/path/to/MPAPI.dll Program.cs
```

Btw, your version of Mono is very old - I definitely recommend getting more recent one.

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked -I had to copy the dll myself, didn't realize it wasn't included (or I don't know where it's hidden) and I'd love to update mono but, well, sys admins...